# What is the unit of spectral density estimated by spec.pgram?

Tags: r, spectral-analysis

The function `spec.pgram` (also called by `spectrum`) in the stats package in R "calculates the periodogram using a fast Fourier transform" - it estimates the spectral density. The documentation is rather short, and it doesn't give information on the units of spectral density. After reading up on this, I'm kind of lost now. I almost never see any units on y axes in published papers. I thought the spectral density is the amplitude at the respective frequencies - would that then be the unit of the original signal? I also often see amplitude^2, referring to power spectral density; or dB; or "dB rel. units^2×δt".

Hence my questions:

Is "spectral density" the same as "power spectral density", and which one is returned by `spec.pgram`?

What is the unit of spectral density returned by `spec.pgram`?